# Working with US customary units of measurements in JSR 363 library

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

I've stumbled upon the JSR unites of measurements library and I'm a little bit lost, now I'm trying to replicate the [demo file](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-demos/blob/master/console/systems/common/src/main/java/tec/uom/demo/systems/common/JSR363Demo.java) that gives the basic idea about how the library works. The thing is that I can't get any of these classes/packages:

```
import static si.uom.SI.*;
import static systems.uom.common.USCustomary.METER;
import static systems.uom.common.USCustomary.MILE;
import static tec.units.ri.unit.MetricPrefix.*;
```

when I type them in my class they're not resolved, now I have downloaded the [JAR](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/measure/unit-api/1.0/) file and Included it in my project, is there anything else I'm supposed to do?

Comment: I made a tentative answer, but to fully answer your question, could you clarify some things? Do you have a `pom.xml` file? If so edit your question and post it's contents. Which IDE are you using to write your code? How did you import your project into the IDE?

Answer (score 1):

When you use maven to handle your project dependencies you don't manually download jars. Instead you use maven to automatically download them. Maven stores information about the project dependencies in a `pom.xml` file. Most Java IDEs can read this pom file and provide autocompletion for clases included in the jars listed as dependencies.

In this case, you should include this in your `pom.xml`, in the `dependencies` section.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.measure</groupId>
    <artifactId>unit-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```